# Form hints with validation

Tags: validation, dom, forms

I'm trying to create a form that has a hints section. When each field is clicked, a section next to it will display a hint, when the form is unfocused, it will validate. In the same section that the hint shows up it will then display whether it is correct or incorrect.

Have the function for validation completed, but I'm dying to trying to make the hints section. It also has to be made using Dom scripting principles no jQuery or other awesome libraries.

Any suggestions on how I can get started. Or even some code that will point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your "hint section" you could try using [this](http://www.maujor.com/blog/pg_apoio/versao-css-puro.html).
For the validation check the source of the standalone version of [livevalidation](http://livevalidation.com/).